# Asynctask and progressbar timing

Tags: android

After pressing ok in dialogbox, I should get data from some place else. so I used Asynctask class. The implementation is below. But after pressing first Ok I wont get any progress bar. I only get it after the second ok is pressed(basically, when all lines inside the button onClick method is executed... 
What should I do to get the progress bar right after pressing first ok?

```
confirmPath= (Button) findViewById(R.id.confirmPath);
            confirmPath.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                        construction
                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Destination.this);
                        builder.setMessage("Press 'Ok' ")
                               .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                                       LoadData task = new LoadData();
                                       task.execute();


                                                                                AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Destination.this).create();
                                    alertDialog.setTitle("Attention!");
                                    alertDialog.setMessage(" Pay attention");
                                     alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                           }
                                        });

                                        alertDialog.show();

                                   }
                               })
                               .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                       // do nothing
                                   }
                               });
                       builder.create();
                       builder.show();
```

And this is the AsynkTask class:

```
public class LoadData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        ProgressDialog progressDialog;
        //declare other objects as per your need
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            progressDialog= ProgressDialog.show(Destination.this, "Progress Dialog Title Text","Please wait", true);

            //do initialization of required objects objects here                
        };      
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
        {   

               ReadFromFile readFromFile= new ReadFromFile();
               readFromFile.ReadAllData("Data");
               //some other tasks to do

            return null;
        }       
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
        {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        };
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Put this code outside AlertDialogBuilder:**

```
LoadData task = new LoadData();
task.execute();
```

**New code should look like:**

```
 @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {


                                       LoadData task = new LoadData();
                                       task.execute();


                        construction
                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Destination.this);
                        builder.setMessage("Press 'Ok' ")
                               .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {


                                                                                AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Destination.this).create();
                                    alertDialog.setTitle("Attention!");
                                    alertDialog.setMessage(" Pay attention");
                                     alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                           }
                                        });

                                        alertDialog.show();

                                   }
                               })
                               .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                       // do nothing
                                   }
                               });
                       builder.create();
                       builder.show();
```

Comment: But I need the data to be sent after I pressed the first ok by alertdialog. But now by ur solution I will get it after I pressed confirmPath which is one step before.. which is wrong

Comment: remove the alert dialog. I don't understand why do you need dialog after clicking the button.

Comment: Icannot remove it. that is the part of warning messages we should give to user. see the answer

Comment: So process cannot start before warning message. You need to click the "Ok" in warning button to proceed with the background process.

Comment: no that progressbar should be visible before the last dialogbox. the problem before was I saw it always after. I should have put the last dialog box in asynktask also

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
    private class NetworkDelegate extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    private ProgressDialog Dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);

    protected String doInBackground(String... pass) {

        try {


            //userid is getting from webservice             

        return userid;

        } catch (Exception e) {

            System.out.println(e);
        }




    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        Dialog.dismiss();

        if (result == null) {
            tv.setText("Enter Your Password Correctly");
            pwet.setFocusable(true);

        } else {



        }

    }

    protected void onPreExecute() {

        Dialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        Dialog.show();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I should have put the second alertdialog also in asynctask `onPostExecute` method. then I have the progressbar before obviously